# Should you follow the style convention in python with old libraries?

Tags: python

From the PEP8 "Function names should be lowercase, with words separated by underscores as necessary to improve readability."

Then we have popular libraries like matplotlib with arguments i.e. `linewidth` and `markersize`, which is apparently doesn't follow the convention. The question is when
you have arguments with the exact same meaning, should you follow the PEP8 or library naming.
I.e. what is generally more acceptable

```py
def show(x, y, line_width, marker_size):
    plt.plot(x, y, linewidth=line_width, markersize=marker_size, marker='o')
    plt.show()
```

or

```py
def show(x, y, linewidth, markersize):
    plt.plot(x, y, linewidth=linewidth, markersize=markersize, marker='o')
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First is better - it's making a bridge from PEP8 style code into old style code, not drawing old style into the new code.

PEP8 says:

> In particular: do not break backwards compatibility just to comply with this PEP!
>
> Some other good reasons to ignore a particular guideline:
>
> 1. When applying the guideline would make the code less readable, even for someone who is used to reading code that follows this PEP.
> 2. To be consistent with surrounding code that also breaks it (maybe for historic reasons) -- although this is also an opportunity to clean up someone else's mess (in true XP style).
> 3. Because the code in question predates the introduction of the guideline and there is no other reason to be modifying that code.
> 4. When the code needs to remain compatible with older versions of Python that don't support the feature recommended by the style guide.

I don't think `linewidth=line_width` is less readable then `linewidth=linewidth`, and there's no other needs to do the second.

Comment: My only reservation is if the user of the code knows the function is a wrapper for matplotlib, they may be more familiar with matplotlib naming.

Comment: I think it's still clear enough.

Answer (score 4):

I'd say it depends on who your code is for. If your library is designed for coders who are familiar with matplotlib and the arguments its functions take (they know what `linewidth` and `markersize` are in the context of matplotlib), use the matplotlib naming. Otherwise use the more standard python naming (snake case). If the rest of your library API uses snake case, then I think it would be more consistent to follow that and "smooth over" the matplotlib naming. From PEP 8:

> Consistency with this style guide is important. Consistency within a project is more important. Consistency within one module or function is the most important.